# The problem of adding buttons and links into placeholder

Tags: php, html, css

The problem of adding buttons and links into placeholder.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14lax.png)

I want to add an Input / Register link below.

```
                <textarea placeholder="entry girebilmek için giriş yapmanız gerekiyor." class="pb-cmnt-textarea" disabled></textarea>
```

even if you want to put a facebook login button here if possible.

Comment: What is your question? Do you want to put a button in a textarea? And why would you do that?

Comment: This is a review area. For non-members, I would like to enter / login button into textarea.

Comment: Your screenshot shows button below text area.  Do you have an image demonstrating specifically what you want?  Do you want the button to hover over the text area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding button inside text area is not really a good idea. You could use absolute position for the button to make it look like its part of the text area though.

```
position: absolute
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
div{
    display:inline;
    position:relative;
}

button{
 position:absolute;
 bottom:10px;
 right:10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
                <textarea placeholder="entry girebilmek için giriş yapmanız gerekiyor." class="pb-cmnt-textarea" disabled rows=10></textarea>
    <button>Login</button>
</div>
```